# Android: how to draw path without overlapping using canvas?

Tags: android, path, android-canvas, point, intersection

I have a 3x3 game board and I need to draw a path from check to check.
game board:
[image: game board]

Using below functions I can draw path with center point of checks.
Canvas function:
drawPath(Path path, Paint paint)
Path function:
lineTo(float x, float y)

draw path like:
[image: path]

However, path are overlapped if path passes through a point over one time.
like this(left: current, right: expected), overlapped at corner:
[image: overlapped at corner]

and this(left: current, right: expected), overlapping lines and corner:
[image: overlapping lines and corner]


Is there a library or technique to due with this kind of problem(draw the right non-overlapped path)?